# Create a tableview with cells that link to videos

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I want to create tableview cells that have a disclosure button that when pressed would link to a local video but I am having problems, when i click on the disclosure button the screen goes black, i am using arc. how can i go about this?

here's my sample code..What am i doing wrong

here is my header file

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

 @interface BIDVideosViewController : UIViewController

 <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *tableList;

 @end
```

Here is my .m file

```
 #import "BIDVideosViewController.h"

 @interface BIDVideosViewController ()
 {
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

 }

 @end

 @implementation BIDVideosViewController

 @synthesize tableList;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[table setDelegate:self];
[table setDataSource:self];
[self.view addSubview:table];
 NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Gangan",@"SwimGood", nil];
self.tableList = array;
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  return [tableList count];
  }
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
 static NSString *DisclosureButtonIdentifier = @"DisclosurebutotonIdentifier";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DisclosureButtonIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault       reuseIdentifier:DisclosureButtonIdentifier];
   }
  NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
   NSString *rowString = [tableList objectAtIndex:row];
  cell.textLabel.text = rowString;
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
  return cell;
  }

  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Gangan" ofType:@"mp4"];
  NSLog(@"path is ...%@", thePath);
  NSURL *theurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];
  MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];
  [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
  [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
  [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
  [moviePlayer play];
```

}

Comment: You don't state what the problem is. And there are the **numberOfSectionsInTableView:** and **tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:** methods?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out..i have inserting the 'numberOfSectionsInTableView' method and added a few lines to the 'ViewDidLoad', though i get the string names of the videos and the disclosure buttons, when i click on them nothing happens, any idea where i may be at fault, please help..thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to subclass `UITableViewController` rather than `UIViewController`?

Comment: how do you mean? @Abizern ...you mean in my header file ?

Comment: @Abizern - that makes absolutely no difference to the problem.

Comment: I didn't say it was - that's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a UITableView or the required `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods.

Try adding

```
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[table setDelegate:self];
[table setDataSource:self];
[self.view addSubview:table];
```

To your `viewDidLoad` function.

Check out the [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [data source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) documentation for the required methods (and available ones too) to properly implement a UITableView. Its nice to do it this way, since it handles everything (drawing and setup) for you. All you have to do is give it the values and it automatically draws it upon loading the data.

Comment: ..wow thanks a million for your input,that was really helpful i have the names of the two videos i want to play displaying on the app as well as the disclosure buttons, however, when i click on them nothing happens, i believe this is just a minor problem, can't figure it out. I have updated my code..please have a look again and let me know what you think..thanks

Comment: Are you sure nothing happens? When I do this, it works just fine. Even the NSLog isn't being output to the console?

Comment: hey man @RileyE thanks again for your input, i had a slight error where the MPMovieController was been implemented..i solved the issues :)

Comment: @dappa Thats great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
NSString *thePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"animation" ofType:@"mov"];
NSLog(@" path is...%@",thePath);
NSURL *theurl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];
```

MPMoviePlayerController  *moviePlayer =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];

```
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];  
[self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
//[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];
```

its worked for me , hope work for you too

Comment: do i know the reason for devoting ?